# Gamma GLMER Error: PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, glmm

I am attempting to run a GLMER with a gamma function in R.

Here is my code:

```
glmer(Exploration ~ Year + Density + No_Hortensis + No_Other_Carabids + (1|Observer) + (1|Week) + (1|TrapNo), data=male, family=Gamma)
```

When I run the GLMER on my original dataset, everything runs smoothly, however once I have subsetted the data to analyse data from males alone, I receive the following error:

```
Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, maxit = 100L,  : 
  (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
```

Removing the variables No_Hortensis and No_Other_Carabids seems to solve the problem, but I really need to include these in the model.

I've tried looking at related pages on the same error message, but I've not been able to solve my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm not very R literate, so please try to explain as simply as possible :)

Thanks!